# PowerBI Visualisation

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I have a tables like this

Table 1

Date                 ID    Category    Product

24-July-2018    1        A             Product1

24-July-2018    2        A             Product2

25-July-2018    2        A             Product2

24-July-2018    3        B             Product3

24-July-2018    4        B             Product3

25-July-2018    5        C             Product2

24-July-2018    1        D             Product1

24-July-2018    2        D             Product2

25-July-2018    2        D             Product2

24-July-2018    3        E             Product3

24-July-2018    4        E             Product3

25-July-2018    5        E             Product2

24-July-2018    1        F             Product1

24-July-2018    2        F             Product2

25-July-2018    2        G             Product2

24-July-2018    3        H             Product3

24-July-2018    4        I             Product3

25-July-2018    5        J             Product2

I want to display top products for each category for top 6 categories by product count for that date(The date column is in filter). For example, if the user selects 24-July-2018 from filter,  the results should be

SubTable1 (B)

Id   Product   Count

1    Product3    2

SubTable2 (D)

Id   Product   Count

1    Product1    1

2    Product3    1

SubTable3 (E)

Id   Product   Count

1    Product3    2

Subtable4 (F)

Id   Product   Count

1   Product1   1

2    Product2   1

Subtable5 (H)

Id   Product   Count

1    Product3   1

Subtable6 (A)

Id   Product    Count

1    Product2   1

and if the filter is 25-July-2018, the results should be -

SubTable1 (A)

Id   Product   Count

1    Product2    1

SubTable2 (C)

Id   Product   Count

1    Product1    1

SubTable3 (D)

Id   Product   Count

1    Product2    1

Subtable4 (E)

Id   Product   Count

1   Product1   1

Subtable5 (G)

Id   Product   Count

1    Product2   1

Subtable6 (J)

Id   Product    Count

1    Product1   1

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you??

If yes you simply need to group by Category and Date. Let me know if this helps

[image]

[image]